# If $f\in k[x]$ and $\deg f \leq n$, then $f(x)=c_1(x - a_1)^n + c_2(x - a_2)^n +\cdots+ c_{n+1}(x - a_{n+1})^n$ for distinct $a_i's$ in $k$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I have been trying the following qual question from Harvard in the year of 1991. You can find it [here](https://www.math.harvard.edu/graduate/study-the-qualifying-exam/some-old-qualifying-exams/).

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ in one variable $x$ over
a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and let $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}$ be any $n + 1$ distinct elements of $k$.

> Show that any polynomial $f(x)\in V$ can be written in the form
> $$f(x)=c_1(x - a_1)^n + c_2(x - a_2)^n +\cdots+ c_{n+1}(x - a_{n+1})^n$$
> for some elements $c_i \in k$. Also this result is false if $\text{char}(k)\neq0$.

Initially I was trying to solve applying division algorithm, but stuck at the last remainder. Then i tried to imitate Lagrange's Interpolation, i.e., tried to show the collection $\mathcal B=\{(x-a_1)^n,\ldots,(x-a_{n+1})^n\}$ form a basis for the $n+1$ dimensional space $V$. I couldn't really do much. Need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $V$ has dimension $\dim V=n+1$ and $\{(x-a_i)^n\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a system of $n+1$ vectors in $V$. Thus, in order to prove that they from a basis it's enough to prove that they are linearly independent. Not sure if this actually easier to show, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional vector space, it's enough to prove that $(n+1)$ vectors $\{(x-a_i)^n\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ are linearly independent.

Suppose the contrary, then there are $c_1,\ldots,c_{n+1}\in k$ not all zero such that the polynomial identity
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c_k(x-a_k)^{n}=0
$$
holds.
Differentiating this equality $m$ times gives
$$
n(n-1)\ldots(n-m+1)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c_k(x-a_k)^{n-m}=0.
$$
However, in our case $\operatorname{char} k=0$, so we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}c_k(x-a_k)^{m}=0,~m=\overline{0,n}.
$$
Now it remains to recall that since not all $c_k$ are zeros, the determinant $\det\{(x-a_k)^m\}_{k,m}$ should be equal to 0. But it's a Vandermonde determinant, so it equals
$$
\det\{(x-a_k)^m\}_{k,m}=\prod_{k<m}((x-a_k)-(x-a_m))=\prod_{k<m}(a_m-a_k)\neq 0
$$
(since all $a_k$ are distinct) and this is a contradiction.

Thus, elements $\{(x-a_i)^n\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ span the whole $V$, as desired.

Comment: It looks promising, like it. Thanks. one more thing: this process wont work in finite ch. field.  but is their any other concrete counter example..i mean independent of the process of solution in 0 ch. field.

Comment: @user371231 Expand $(x-a)^p$ in characteristic $p$ and draw your conclusions.

Comment: @darij grinberg In characteristic $p$, choosing $n=p$, $(x-a)^p=x^p-a^p$, then no nonzero polynomial of degree less than $p$ can be expressed as a $k$-linear combination of the polynomials $(x^p-a_i^{p})$ for $i=1,\ldots,p+1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, these polynomials span only two-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{lin}\{x^p,1\}$ in $V$.